# Calculate raster landcover area in multiple overlapping buffers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, land-cover, intersect, tabulate

I have 900 1km buffers (polygons) in one layer and a raster layer for forest area (reclassified into forest 1, non forest 0).
I have tried:

1. **Tabulate area** - but realised this does not work for overlapping polygons
2. **Convert Raster to Polygon** - Intersect and then calculate geometry for area but I'm getting areas equal to the pixel size of the raster (100mx100m= 10,000) and I'm not sure how to convert this back to m2...

Comment: If the native units are in metres then there is no conversion. If you want to process the output as Km2 then you divide the area by 1,000,000.

Comment: You could also Dissolve your polygons, and then tabulate area.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/371783/zonal-statistics-2-ends-up-causing-a-fatal-error-is-there-an-alternative/371790#371790

Comment: Hi all, so my method of converting to polygon and intersecting seems ok? At this point overlapping polygons shouldnt matter? 

@ycartwhelen could you clarify am i dissolving my converted raster?

Comment: Following up on @FelixIP's comment, Dissolve -> Zonal Statistics as Table would be more efficient than converting from raster to polygon and then using Tabulate.