# Taking min and max values out of certain polygons

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcmap, polygon, spatial-analyst

I have taken out DEM data over a specific area and converted the raster to polygons.

Now I want to code so I get the max value and the min value of "gridcode" of every set of polygons that are connected to each other. The polygons that are disconnected are in the same layer so I need so seperate the disconnected polygons before making a for loop which test the min and max value.

Do anyone have an efficient solution?

[image]

My Code:

```
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:\Users\daniel\Studier\Applikationsutveckling\Projekt\Gavle'


pulka_pol = r'C:\Users\daniel\Studier\Applikationsutveckling\Projekt\Gavle\Gavle_projekt.gdb\Pulka.shp'

demdata_gavle = r'C:\Users\daniel\Studier\Applikationsutveckling\Projekt\Gavle\Demdata2\Demdata.tif'

outExtractByMask = ExtractByMask(demdata_gavle, pulka_pol)

if arcpy.Exists("mask_extract.tif"):
    arcpy.management.Delete("mask_extract.tif")

outExtractByMask.save("mask_extract.tif")

outPolygons = r'C:\Users\daniel\Studier\Applikationsutveckling\Projekt\Gavle\dem_poly.shp'
arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion(outExtractByMask, outPolygons, "NO_SIMPLIFY", "VALUE")
```

Comment: Zonal statistics as table does it. Why script?

Comment: The thing is that if i do that i will receive statistics over all polygons, i need some way of seperating the cluster of polygons that intersects and taking zonal statistics of them after i seperated them is this possible?

Comment: Dissolve into single parts or use statistics 2

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/371783/zonal-statistics-2-ends-up-causing-a-fatal-error-is-there-an-alternative/371790#371790

Comment: Sounds like you need region group then zonal statistics as table, no converting to vector required.