# Problem with overlapping buffers and tabulate area tool

Tags: arcmap, buffer, overlapping-features

I use the tabulate area tool. Unfortunately, this tool does not work properly with overlapping buffers (which are the majority in my shapefile), meaning that most of the buffers have a smaller area than it should be. Apparently, the area of intersection is fully considered only for one buffer, for all the overlapping ones only the areas without intersection are considered by the tool.

I found that I can use the ModelBuilder to solve the problem. I’ve never used a model builder before, so I tried to do it following a scheme I found on the internet, but it doesn’t work.

Is this model correct for my purpose? Could you tell me I can, I make it work? Or do you know any other way to solve my problem?
I’m using ArcMap 10.8.1. My original land use file was in vector format, so I had to convert it to raster before using the tabulate map.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by  " it doesn’t work"? Edit your question to include more detail, rather than stick it here in the comments.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/371783/zonal-statistics-2-ends-up-causing-a-fatal-error-is-there-an-alternative/371790#371790